# Why won't my music play?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

It's possible to play your own music in Euro Truck Simulator 2 by putting music files in your music folder. I've done this, and the music does show up in the in-game music list, but when I play the music it doesn't do anything. I'm trying to play MP3 files, which according to the readme file and online resources is supported by the game.

What do I need to do to get my music to play in-game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to play music in-game your computer will need the proper codecs. Without them the game won't be able to play MP3 files (or other types of music). The [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://codecguide.com/) contains various music codecs, and can be downloaded [here.](http://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) You'll only need the Basic version in order to get MP3 files to work.

Comment: Did the readme and online resources really not mention this?  It's like if Minecraft started advertizing that it has the Aether, but not mentioning that you need to download a mod to do it.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: The readme does mention it, but the way in which it's worded makes it sound like it has a codec for playing MP3 files already built in, and a codec is only required if you wish to play other types of music files.

Comment: @Batophobia no, it's more like: to be able to browse the web, you need to install a web browser.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was I download Real Player and used it to convert the music to MP3. But having said that you need to be aware that to play music all music files MUST be MP3 only.

When you've got the files you want just copy & paste them into the music folder in the *ETS2* folder.